# Splitting strings at lower case characters and numbers

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I'm trying to split the strings of chemicals into their elements and numbers.

See this example

`"Fe3O4"` will be split into `{"Fe","3","O","4"}`

I've tried using `StringSplit` and various `_LowerCaseQ` type patters but it isn't working. I've also tried using `StringSplit[#,""]` to split everything and then finding the lower case characters and putting it back together but I haven't got it to work. Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I propose:

```
StringCases[
  {"Fe3O4", "CO", "MgO", "Uut14AuO6"},
  DigitCharacter .. | (_?UpperCaseQ ~~ ___?LowerCaseQ)
]
```

> ```
> {{"Fe", "3", "O", "4"}, {"C", "O"}, {"Mg", "O"}, {"Uut", "14", "Au", "O", "6"}}
> ```

Or as a `RegularExpression`:

```
StringCases[
  {"Fe3O4", "CO", "MgO", "Uut14AuO6"},
  RegularExpression["\\d+|[A-Z][a-z]*"]
]
```

Comment: Very nice, simple and elegant. +1

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks! :-)  Hopefully it makes up for my earlier blunder.

Comment: It does :). And I really like the RegEx version too.

Comment: Patterns blow my mind.

Comment: @s0rce Thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer one of @Mr.Wizard's solutions based on `StringCases`, but here is a solution using `StringSplit`:

```
StringSplit["Fe3O4", RegularExpression["(?=[A-Z]|\\d)"]]
(* {"Fe", "3", "O", "4"} *)
```

It splits the string at any position that is followed by an upper case letter or a digit.  If multiple digits are possible:

```
StringSplit["Fe23O42", RegularExpression["(?=[A-Z]|(?<!\\d)\\d)"]]
(* {"Fe", "23", "O", "42"} *)
```

This is the same except that now a digit may not be preceded by another digit.

Comment: A powerful use of regular expressions.  Is it possible to write this as a `StringExpression`?  I can't think of a way at the moment.

Comment: No, regex is the only way to express look-ahead or look-behind conditions.  A shame, really, because regex patterns are ugly as [sin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/211232)... but it sure is nice to have the PCRE engine to draw upon for those tougher jobs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
chemSplit[s_String] := 
 Module[{pos = StringPosition[s, {_?UpperCaseQ, NumberString}, Overlaps -> False][[All, 1]]},
  StringSplit@StringInsert[s, " ", pos]
 ]

chemSplit["Fe3O4"]
```

> ```
> {"Fe", "3", "O", "4"}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
elements = SortBy[ElementData[#, "Abbreviation"] & /@ ElementData[], Minus@*StringLength];
StringCases["Fe3O2", DigitCharacter .. | elements]
```

> `{"Fe", "3", "O", "2"}`

(Thanks to Mr.Wizard for syntax improvements.)

Comment: There is a precision about this that I like, and I can see the effort that you put into it. +1  One could replace the second part with:  `StringCases[string, DigitCharacter .. | elements]` if desired.  Also, these string functions are set up to work with lists of patterns so I believe you can drop the `Apply[Alternatives,` part.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, I like your version better so I incorporated it in the answer.

Comment: +1 for `@*`, there is always something new to learn!

Answer (score 2):

Just to be different

```
f = Flatten[List @@@ WolframAlpha["formula " <> #, "Result"][[1, 1]]] &;
f /@ {"Fe2O3", "MgO"}
```

> {{"Fe", 2, "O", 3}, {"Mg", "O"}}

This approach seems to be stupid, but it can be easily extended to another chemical data (e.g. molar mass).

Comment: ybeltukov I am happy to see you posting again!  Unfortunately you fell into the same trap I did; see the edit history of my answer. :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I also happy to join you again! When I try to correct my answer I come to your answer exactly. I propose another approach instead of deleting the post :)