# Splitting strings into letter keys and integers

Tags: string-manipulation, algorithm

I have strings of the following form:

```
string = "ABC123DEFG456HI89UZXX1";
```

Letter keys of variable lengths are followed by (positive) integers.

I want to get this transformation:

> {{"ABC", 123}, {"DEFG", 456}, {"HI", 89}, {"UZXX", 1}}

I have written:

```
chars = Characters @ string;

runs = Length /@ Split[IntegerQ @ ToExpression @ # & /@ chars]
```

> {3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1}

```
takes = Transpose[{# - runs + 1, #}] & [Accumulate @ runs]
```

> {{1, 3}, {4, 6}, {7, 10}, {11, 13}, {14, 15}, {16, 17}, {18, 21}, {22,
>   22}}

```
 result =
    Partition[StringJoin /@ Map[Take[chars, #] &, takes], 2] /.
       {a_String, b_String} :> {a, ToExpression @ b}
```

> {{"ABC", 123}, {"DEFG", 456}, {"HI", 89}, {"UZXX", 1}}

I have two questions:

**(1)** How could the above coding be shortened / improved? (it seems to be too long for such a trivial problem)

**(2)** How would a "direct" method (`StringCases` , `StringSplit` ...) look like?

Comment: Related: [(58376)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58376)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You asked for shortened, improved, so here it is using `RegularExpressions`:

```
StringCases[string, RegularExpression["(\\D+)(\\d+)"] :> {"$1", ToExpression["$2"]}]
```

> ```
> {{"ABC", 123}, {"DEFG", 456}, {"HI", 89}, {"UZXX", 1}}
> ```

Here's a version using `StringSplit`:

```
Partition[StringSplit[string, RegularExpression["(\\d+)"] :> FromDigits @ "$1"], 2]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
string = "ABC123DEFG456HI89UZXX1";

Partition[StringSplit[string, x : NumberString :> ToExpression@x], 2]
```

or

```
Partition[StringSplit[string, x : NumberString :> FromDigits@x], 2]
```

or

```
Split[StringSplit[string, x : NumberString :> FromDigits@x], Head@#2 === Integer &]
(* {{"ABC",123},{"DEFG",456},{"HI",89},{"UZXX",1}} *)
```

Comment: Somehow amazing that your short poem works. But inspecting it with `Trace` it became clearer to me :)

Answer (score 7):

With all the answers we need a timing comparison.

Functions:

```
bel[string_] := 
  StringSplit[string, 
    PatternSequence[x : Longest[LetterCharacter ..], 
      y : Longest[DigitCharacter ..]] :> {x, ToExpression@y}][[;; ;; 2]];
RK1[string_] := 
  StringCases[string, RegularExpression["(\\D+)(\\d+)"] :> {"$1", ToExpression["$2"]}];
RK2[string_] := 
  Partition[StringSplit[string, RegularExpression["(\\d+)"] :> FromDigits@"$1"], 2];
ybk[string_] := 
  Partition[#, 2] &@StringSplit[string, x : DigitCharacter .. :> ToExpression@x];
kg1[string_] := Partition[StringSplit[string, x : NumberString :> ToExpression@x], 2];
kg2[string_] := Partition[StringSplit[string, x : NumberString :> FromDigits@x], 2];
kuba[string_] := 
  StringCases[string, x : LetterCharacter .. ~~ y : NumberString :> {x, ToExpression@y}];
al1[string_] := Module[{nu, le},
   nu = ToExpression[StringCases[string, DigitCharacter ..]];
   le = StringCases[string, LetterCharacter ..];
   Transpose[{le, nu}]
   ];
al2[string_] := Module[{nu, le},
   nu = ToExpression[StringSplit[string, __?LetterQ]];
   le = StringSplit[string, __?DigitQ];
   Transpose[{le, nu}]
   ];
```

Generator:

```
g = "a" <> RandomChoice[
     Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ {{2, 10}, {1, 26}} -> 
      CharacterRange["0", "Z"]~Drop~{11, 17}, #] <> "1" &;
```

Benchmark Plot:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{bel, RK1, RK2, ybk, kg1, kg2, kuba, al1, al2}, g, "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]
(click for larger)

All methods have similar complexity except Algohi's second method which incurs a heavy penalty.

The winning method is kguler's second function, followed closely by RunnyKine's second function which is nearly the same thing except for the use of regular expressions.

Comment: Could you please test my edited answer? (I've replaced RuleDelayed by Rule)

Comment: @belisarius Why did you revert my correction of your broken code?

Comment: Did I? I wasn't aware of it. Please forgive me

Answer (score 6):

Without Reg. Exp.:

```
string = "ABC123DEFG456HI89UZXX1";
StringSplit[string, PatternSequence[x : LetterCharacter .., y : DigitCharacter ..] :>
                                                   {x, ToExpression@y}][[;; ;; 2]]
(* {{"ABC", "123"}, {"DEFG", "456"}, {"HI", "89"}, {"UZXX", "1"}} *)
```

Comment: @RunnyKine Yup. Thanks

Comment: You come to `StringCases` with these revisions :)

Comment: This code is currently broken due to the use of `->` rather than `:>` in the rule.  This means that `ToExpression@y` directly evaluates to `y`, therefore its existence is pointless and the output is in the wrong format. (Also `x` and `y` are not localized.)  I corrected this but the edit was reverted.

Answer (score 6):

`StringSplit` with `Partition` works fine for this particular case

```
Partition[#, 2] &@StringSplit[string, x : DigitCharacter .. :> ToExpression@x]
(* {{"ABC", 123}, {"DEFG", 456}, {"HI", 89}, {"UZXX", 1}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
StringCases[string, 
            x : LetterCharacter .. ~~ y : NumberString :> {x, ToExpression@y}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
nu = ToExpression[StringCases[string, DigitCharacter ..]];
le = StringCases[string, LetterCharacter ..];
Transpose[{le, nu}]
```

using StringSplit:

```
nu = ToExpression[StringSplit[string, __?LetterQ]];
le = StringSplit[string, __?DigitQ];
Transpose[{le, nu}]
```